# Receiving undefined when trying to use FOR JSON in MSSQL and trying to read the root key

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, npm

I am trying to use a JSON result from MSSQL npm package and a Azure Database the results are in JSON but when i have tried to use bracket or dot notation it returns undefined. 
this is what it returns and i am trying to access the personalNames node
[ { 'JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B':
     '{"personalNames":[{"id":"H0AK00014","name":"WHITTAKER RICHARD"}} ]

```
req.query("SELECT TOP 3 CAND_ID AS id, REPLACE(CAND_NAME, '\"', '') AS name FROM [dbo].[Merge_FEC_80_18] FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('personalNames')")
   .then(function (recordset) {
     console.log(recordset.recordset[0].personalNames);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the JSON this returns is only this part:

```
{"personalNames":[{"id":"H0AK00014", . . .
```

That JSON document is returned to the client in single-column resultset.  So you need to get the string value from the first row of the resultset, and that's your JSON.